# Host name site collections, access from different machine

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sitecollection

I have created 2 host name site collections
http://site1.dev.com.au and
http://site2.dev.com.au

I have added these 2 entries in host file
127.0.0.0      site1.dev.com.au and
127.0.0.0      site2.dev.com.au

I can access both sites, now I am trying to access these sites from a different machine, both entries have been added to DNS.

I have checked default IIS application running on port 80 is stopped becasue my sharepoint web application is also running on port 80. When i try to access site1.dev.com.au from a different machine I see default IIS page, why is that happening? It should show sharepoint site.

How can I fix this issue.
Do I need to remove entries from host file?
Do I need to add bindings in IIS web application

Comment: Have you set the correct IP on DNS ? From other machine you can ping the DNS name entries ?

Comment: you are right, IP was wrong and it was pointing to a different a web server.